# Save bookmarks on Android app - Sqlite DB for each user

Tags: android, android-listview

I use sqlite for my DB which is packages as an asset within the app. When you open the app you are presented with 10-12 items in a listview and then you can click on any item to show the detailed view.

My Sqlite consists of 1 table and 11 fields.
These are id , story name , story details , story age and so on and so forth.

I now want the ability for individual users to store any story as their favorite. They can bookmark a story and from a particular view be able to view that story later.

How can I achive this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Create another table** in your sqlite Db with two fields say userid and storyid. Then as you mentioned in another view, call this table to refer to bookmark story of your user by using **where query refering user id**

```
"Select * from tab_name where userid = '"+ User_ref +"'";
```

Comment: I am just wondering about the implications of this on the app.My app has over 3000 active users and am wondering if that grew to 10K would that bloat the app.  Also does this mean each user would now have an id ?

Comment: Well, YES..if you want the ability for individual users to store any story as their favorite then unique **userID** is must.